# "Unknown provider: uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider" al probar con Jasmine código que usa el componente de Google Maps para AngularJS

Tags: google-maps, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Para un proyecto web en el que estoy participando usamos el componente [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps). Este es el código `JavaScript` que hace referencia al componente y lo inicializa:

```
var configureGoogleMaps = function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        libraries: 'geometry,visualization'
    });
}
configureGoogleMaps.$inject = ['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider'];

angular
    .module('shTools.Map', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
    .directive('map', mapDirective)
    .config(configureGoogleMaps);
```

donde `mapDirective` define un elemento HTML que contiene el componente de Google Maps.

Esto está funcionando como se espera. El problema es que cuando ejecuto un simple test usando `Jasmine` con `Karma`, obtengo el error `Unknown provider: uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider`. Por alguna razón no está siendo capaz de encontrar el proveedor.

He intentado crear un `mock` para forzar la creación de un proveedor con ese nombre, pero no ha funcionado:

```
angular.module('uiGmapgoogle-maps', [])
    .value('uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', {
        configure: function() {}
    });
```

¿Qué podría estar pasando aquí?

Comment: Quizás olvidaste incluir el js en la configuración de karma (karma.config.js)? Ej:    files: [
      '../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      '../src/*.js',
      './*.js'
    ],

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los proveedores de AngularJs de inyectan de forma distinta al resto de servicios por lo que también hay que inyectarlos de forma especial cuando escribes las pruebas con Jasmine.

La forma de hacerlo consiste en crear un módulo falso en el que se inyecta el proveedor

```
beforeEach(function () {   
     // Módulo falso donde se inyecta el proveedor
     angular.module('testApp', function () {})
       .config(['bilingualButtonConfigProvider', function (provider) {
         bilingualButtonConfigProvider = provider;
       }]);
     // Inicializar módulos
     module('myApp', 'testApp');
});
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo completo [aquí](http://jsfiddle.net/ff7y1xmr/)

También dejo unos enlaces interesantes:

- [Creating Configurable Angular Directives with Providers](http://benclinkinbeard.com/posts/creating-configurable-angular-directives-with-providers/): en este artículo se puede aprender un poco más del comportamiento de los proveedores
- [Testing  angular providers with Jasmine](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/qTvMz/): Otro ejemplo en JsFiddle de pruebas con proveedores (es en el que me he basado yo)

Espero que te ayude